# Repository/Directory View

Tags: apache, wamp

I just transferred my website to a new machine. I have game servers that pull contents of a directory by looking in a specified website folder for files of the specified extension and loading them into the server.

After the the transfer, this function is not working as the specified website folder returns as a 404. IF i navigate in a browser to a specific file in that folder the browser will display the content properly. How do I enable the 'directory contents' view of a web directory that does not contain an index.* file?

In my http-vhosts file I have;

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/public"
    ServerName public
    ServerAlias www.REDACTED.REDACTED
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

in the httpd.conf I also have 'Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI'

Comment: Check if your mod_autoindex is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

As you redacted the ServerAlias and not the ServerName I assume they must be different, they should be like this using `example.com` for example

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/public"
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If you want the site visible to you locally you need to put this in the HOSTS file

```
127.0.0.1  example.com
::1  example.com
```

If you want people to actually get access from the universe as `Require all granted` suggests then you have to have either registered `example.com` and pointed it at your routers WAN IP Address, and port forwarded your routers port 80 to the PC running WAMPServer.

If you are only interested in using this internally `Require local` is better/safer/self documenting